# How to validate a model utilizing DataAnnotations attributes without it being mapped to EF context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, data-annotations

You can validate a model object with EF 5 Code-First like that:

```
var validationResult = db.Entry(someModel).GetValidationResult();
```

But what if your model class is not mapped in your `DbContext` implementation and you're planning to pass it directly to sproc via `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`. How do you validate your model before passing it to sproc in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(model);
var validationResult = new List<ValidationResult>();
Validator.TryValidateObject(model, validationContext , validationResult);
```